# cout with function of a class

Tags: c++, class

I just took class in 'classes' and when I try to practice and to run it... there's an error! apparently it's correct but it says `"no operating "<<" matches these operands"`.

Also, I tried `cin >> stu1.add(x);` but it happens to be also an error! I can't do this?

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class stu{
    private:
        string name;
        int id;
    public:
        // constructor
        stu(){
            id=0;
        }
        void add(int id){
            cin >> name >> id;
        }
        void setname(string N){
            name=N;
        }
        void setid(int I){
            id=I;
        }
        string getname(){
            return name;
        }
        int getid(){
            return id;
        }
        void print(int id){
            cout << name << id;
        }
};


int main(){
    stu stu1;
    int x;
    string y;
    cout << "enter name then id:";
    cin >> y;
    stu1.setname(y);
    cin >> x;
    stu1.setid(x);
    cout << stu1.print(x);

    //cout << "name: " << stu1.getname() << endl;
    //cout << "id: " << stu1.getid() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your concept (made up in your mind) is wrong. Please look up istream/ostream operators (maybe manipulators, too). A proper design would not use any cin/cout inside the class `stu`.

Comment: @DieterLücking My teacher said you have to write `cout/cin` with the function.. I doubt that too :\

Comment: And get rid of the method `add(...)`. It's wrong and not used ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to either:

1. change your `print()` function to return the `std::string` value that you want `main()` to write to `cout`:

   ```
   #include <sstream>

   string print(int id){
       ostringstream oss;
       oss << name << id;
       return oss.str();
   }
   ```

   ```
   cout << stu1.print(x);
   ```
2. leave `print()` returning a `void` and writing to `cout` directly, and then remove the `cout` from main():

   ```
   void print(int id){
       cout << name << id;
   }
   ```

   ```
   stu1.print(x);
   ```

With that said, your `print()` method doesn't need to have an input parameter since you should display the class variable `id` which has been set previously:

```
string print(){
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << name << id;
    return oss.str();
}
```

```
void print(){
    cout << name << id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ostream. First add this function out of your class :

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, stu const & s)
{
  s.print(os);
  return os;
}
```

Then modify the print method :

```
  void print(std::ostream &os) const
  {
    os << id << name;
  }
```

Finally you can just do :

```
 cout << stu1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` doesn't return anything, hence the `void` part of the signature.  Your function prints; it doesn't provide anything *to* print.  So... just call it:

```
stu1.print(x);
```

Comment: it works!! I doubt that because my teacher said you have to write 'cout' !! again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since stu::print method has a return value of void it's return type cannot be used with cout.

You should either use

```
stu1.print(x);
```

or

```
cout << stu1.getId();
```